# R plotly show only labels where percentage value is value is above 10

Tags: r, pie-chart, label, plotly

I am making a pie-chart in plotly in R.
I want my labels to be on the chart, so I use `textposition = "inside"`, and for the very small slices those values are not visible.
I am trying to find a way to exclude those labels.
Ideally, I would like to like to not print any lables on my plot that are below 10%.
Setting `textposition = "auto"` doesn't work well, since there are a lot of small slices, and it makes the graph look very messy.
Is there a way to do it?

For example these piecharts from plotly website (https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/)

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

cut <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

color <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

clarity <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

plot_ly(cut, labels = cut, values = count, type = "pie", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1)),
        name = "Cut", showlegend = F) %>%
  add_trace(data = color, labels = color, values = count, type = "pie", domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0.4, 1)),
            name = "Color", showlegend = F) %>%
  add_trace(data = clarity, labels = clarity, values = count, type = "pie", domain = list(x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = c(0, 0.6)),
            name = "Clarity", showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts with Subplots")
```

In the plot for Clarity 1.37% are outside of the plot, while I would like them not to show at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to specify sector labels manually like so:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(category = LETTERS[1:10],
                 value = sample(1:50, size = 10))
# Create sector labels
pct <- round(df$value/sum(df$value),2)
pct[pct<0.1] <- 0  # Anything less than 10% should be blank
pct <- paste0(pct*100, "%")
pct[grep("0%", pct)] <- ""

# Install devtools
# install.packages("devtools")
# Install latest version of plotly from github
# devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")

# Plot
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df, 
        labels = ~category,  # Note formula since plotly 4.0
        values = ~value,  # Note formula since plotly 4.0
        type = "pie",
        text = pct,  # Manually specify sector labels
        textposition = "inside",
        textinfo = "text"  # Ensure plotly only shows our labels and nothing else
        )
```

Check out https://plot.ly/r/reference/#pie for more information...

Comment: Thank you, that is a great idea, however my problem remains as I already use "text" for hoverinfo: hoverinfo = "text", text = sprintf("%s: %s%%", category, value), so it doesn't show any unnecessary information.

Comment: @royr2 is it possible to leave the 'slice of the pie' but instead of putting a line and the percentage, just put a star and a footnote that states there were say 4 groups each forming <1% of the pie?